# Thinkpad T430 Reboots after Resume

Tags: debian, thinkpad

My ThinkPad T430 (Debian 10.3) often winds up in a state where it reboots instead of resuming after the computer goes to sleep. Interestingly, this *only* happens if the computer runs out of power and it eventually resolves itself after a few days/weeks. I've combed logs and `dmesg` but don't see any obvious errors.

Could anyone tell my why this might be happening or suggest which log files I should be looking at and what I should be looking for?

Comment: I rarely let a Windows machine run out of power when suspended (could take many days). You are using Linux and I suggest you use the Hibernate function instead of Suspend which is vastly less likely to run out of power (turns off and saves machine state). This will work much better for you.